# What is the difference between isAlpha and isLetter?

Tags: haskell, char

In Haskell, the function `Data.Char.isAlpha` checks if a character is a letter, but so does `Data.Char.isLetter`. Is there any real difference between these functions, or are they interchangeable?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looking at the [sources](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.1.0/doc/html/src/Data-Char.html) they appear to be equivalent.

Here is the definition of `isLetter` as defined in 4.3.1.0

```
-- derived character classifiers

-- | Selects alphabetic Unicode characters (lower-case, upper-case and
-- title-case letters, plus letters of caseless scripts and modifiers letters).
-- This function is equivalent to 'Data.Char.isAlpha'.
isLetter :: Char -> Bool
isLetter c = case generalCategory c of
        UppercaseLetter         -> True
        LowercaseLetter         -> True
        TitlecaseLetter         -> True
        ModifierLetter          -> True
        OtherLetter             -> True
        _                       -> False
```

And the [definition](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-Unicode.html#isAlpha) of `isAlpha`:

```
-- | Selects alphabetic Unicode characters (lower-case, upper-case and
-- title-case letters, plus letters of caseless scripts and modifiers letters).
-- This function is equivalent to 'Data.Char.isLetter'.
isAlpha                 :: Char -> Bool
isAlpha    c = iswalpha (fromIntegral (ord c)) /= 0
```

They appear to have different implementations, but they are documented to have the same effect.

Answer (score 9):

There's no real difference now. From [the docs](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Data-Char.html#v%3AisAlpha):

> `isAlpha :: Char -> Bool`
>   Selects alphabetic Unicode characters (lower-case, upper-case and title-case letters, plus letters of caseless scripts and modifiers letters). This function is equivalent to Data.Char.isLetter.