# Why does haskell keep both isAlpha and isLetter?

Tags: haskell

From the book *learn you a haskell*, I found `isAlpha` and `isLetter` both check whether a character is a letter.

And I found a question and answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13501559/what-is-the-difference-between-isalpha-and-isletter), which says that there is no difference between these two functions.

Now, I am wondering why `haskell` keeps them both? For a historical reason?

I found an explanation [here](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/beginners/2012-September/010595.html), it says keeping two both for **backward compatibility**, but I am not sure whether it's the reason exactly.

Does anyone knows further more?

Comment: The answer is pretty clear from the link you posted.  You wouldn't want to break any older programs if you removed `isAlpha`.

Comment: It's a bit odd that the implementation is different though they're identical.. usually one would just do `isAlpha = isLetter`.

Comment: Do you have a reason to doubt the sources you found...?

Comment: @DanielWagner Actually no, but not sure either, so asked this question to confirm. Hope did not bring any trouble.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**NOTE: The following is only targetted for ghc**

Walking around the [git log of ghc's source](https://github.com/ghc/ghc) and [archive of Haskell Cafe](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe) , I found some information to answer your question. Although it is not a direct answer, and full of junk informations, hope this helps.

### isAlpha came first

`isAlpha` was already included in [initial revision](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/commit/e7d21ee4f8ac907665a7e170c71d59e13a01da09) in 1996.

### Early 2005: Enhancement of unicode support in ghc

In the early 2005, Dimitry Golubovsky posted [this question](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2005-January/008288.html) about how well did the ghc support unicode well. He was [one of the developer of the unicode patch of hugs](http://www.haskellers.com/user/golubovsky). Maybe he wanted to enhance the unicode support of ghc.

later he left [this post](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2005-June/010569.html)

> Before (i. e. up to and including 6.4), Unicode stuff was handled
>   through wc* locale based functions for wide chars conversion. Since
>   not every installation of Unix (or some other OS) has this set up
>   properly (mine was not: personal itch), this code was proposed for GHC
>   and finally made it there.

### Mar 14 2005: isLetter was added

To enhance the support of unicode, some function such as `isLetter`, `isMark`, `isNumber`, ..., was added in [this commit](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/commit/2b179f023136bb22103856f74e44de281f31be82) . The comment of the commit says that:

> Add Dimitry Golubovsky 's Unicode character
>   class implementation.  This will remove the dependency on libc's
>   locale code and give us much more consistent support for Unicode
>   across platforms.

and in `Unicode.hs`

> These are copied from Hugs Unicode.hs

### Mar 16 2005: Comment that "both two are equivalent" was added

Two days later, [this commit](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/commit/56f0efe81e1b54ca498fd28ac8de958ce955194d) added these two comments.

```
-- This function is equivalent to 'Data.Char.isAlpha'.
isLetter :: Char -> Bool
-- This function is equivalent to 'Data.Char.isLetter'.
isAlpha :: Char -> Bool
```

I couldn't find the reason why this comment was added, but my hyphothesis is -- since `isAlpha` already seemed to support unicode, both function was considered to be equivalent.

### Conclusion

`isAlpha` is the oldest, and `isLetter` was added later together with some other unicode functions which were taken from hugs, so maybe there was no reason to remove only `isLetter` from the set of functions. I din't have enough time to investigate further, but I wrote all the information I researched.